# Why are apps taking up more space?

Tags: applications, internal-storage

I have a micromax A300 and it comes with an internal memory of around 25 GB. The problem is that my memory dedicated to installing apk file which is around 1.2 gb seems to be showing 200MB more data than the amount being used by the apps.

According to the phone I have around 464 mb of apps...

[image]

<sup>Click image for larger version</sup>

but when I click on the "apps" icon it shows:

[image]

<sup>Click image for larger version</sup>

I don't understand why it shows an excess of 200MB being occupied. It has android 4.4.2 and my phone is not rooted. Any help on how I could delete these files would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The extra space is taken up by system apps so you will always see this difference. Once you root your phone and install app like Titanium backup then you can delete some of the pre packaged apps which can't be deleted otherwise.

**Caution: Don't go on deleting system apps as you may face random crashes while using your phone.**